# NPE while accessing a primitive type (double) of instantiated and constructor-configured immutable object. (no autoboxing or reflection involved)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here's the weird exception I am getting with relevant code referenced below:

> 23:51:39 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.actions.c.run(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.actions.TesterAction.yw(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.actions.TesterAction.yX(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.agent.tester.b.Bc(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.agent.tester.r.run(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at com.dk.agent.tester.b.a(Unknown Source)
>   23:51:39 at scal.Scal.onBar(Scal.java:241)
>   23:51:39 at scal.Supres.evalSupres(Scal.java:2678)
>   23:51:39 at scal.SR.supp(Scal.java:2187)
>   23:51:39 at scal.SR.evaluateSRfor(Scal.java:2361)
>   23:51:39 at scal.SR.isAtSR(Scal.java:2385)
>   23:51:39 at scal.SR$Con.access$5(Scal.java:1741)
>   23:51:39 java.lang.NullPointerException

Oh, before you ask, yes, all classes of this app are in one file. Don't ask why. That's just how it is. Below are the references with code to the above stack trace:

```
ref. scal.Scal.onBar(Scal.java:241):
        try{
        for(Ins instr : supresSourceMap.keySet())
            for(Per p : supresSourceMap.get(instr).keySet())
    241:        supresSourceMap.get(instr).get(p).evalSupres(currTime);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(console.getErr());
            }
ref. scal.Supres.evalSupres(Scal.java:2678):
    public void evalSupres(long time) throws Exception{
        ...
    2678:   sup.supp(Con.of(getIns(), getPer(), center, time, conRange, true), null);
        ...
    }
ref. scal.SR.supp(Scal.java:2187):
    void supp(Con nHt, Con remove){
        ...
    2187    evaluateSRfor(nHt);
        ...
    }
ref. scal.SR.evaluateSRfor(Scal.java:2361):
    private void evaluateSRfor(Con nHt) {
        if(!hits.get(nHt.per).isEmpty()){
            Con lastHt = getLastHt(nHt.per);
            if(lastHt != null){
                if(lastHt.srSource == null){
                    if(isNewSR(nHt)){
                        addNewSR(nHt);
                    }
                }else{
    2361:           if(isAtSR(nHt)){
                        addConToLastSR(nHt);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
ref. scal.SR.isAtSR(Scal.java:2385):
            private boolean isAtSR(Con nHt) {
                ...
    2385:       double high = nHt.getHighestCon().upperConBound;
                ...
            }
        ref. nHt.getHighestCon() :
            Con getHighestCon(){
                Con highCon = null;
                boolean contains = false;
                if(this.srSource != null){
                    highCon = srSource.getFirst();
                    for(Con con : srSource){
                        if(!contains)
                            contains = this.equals(con);
                        if (con.compareTo(highCon) > 0) {
                            highCon = con;
                        }
                    }
                if(!contains) throw new IllegalStateException("getHighestCon(): " + this.toString() + " does not belong to its srSource list: " + srSource.toString());
                }
                return highCon;
            }
ref. scal.SR$Con.access$5(Scal.java:1741):
    1741:   private final double upperConBound;
```

Important notes:

- srSource is a field in the Con class of LinkedList<> type.
- Method getHighestCon() is defined within Con type.
- The type Con is a static inner class within type SR.
- The Con type is immutable, although srSource list is not final, and is instantiated and populated later on from a setter method.
- Every Con instance holds a reference to itself within srSource list.
- I implemented the Con type with hashCode(), equals(), toString(), Comparable (compareTo(Conf c)). None of them uses the srSource field in its calculations.
- Field "private final double upperConBound" is initialized from constructor of Con via static method:

  - this.upperConBound = value + Utils.pValue(ins, conRange);
- The problem does not disappear if I access the field via method instead of directly.
- However, the problem disappears when I access the upperConBound field from isAtSR() like this:

  - double high = getHighestCon(srSource).upperConfBound;
- Where:

  - srSource a field of SR instance and
  - the method getHighestCon(LinkedList<> srSource) is implemented in the SR type in the same way as it is in Con type, but accessing the parameter instead of a field and not throwing exception.
  - Bear in mind that the solution above is not the solution I am after. I need the getHighestCon() method to be implemented and working from within Con type.
    If you have any questions or need more code samples, please do let me know. I appreciate your time spent on solving this for me.

Comment: Aaaah, too much code.  Please boil this down to a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you reproduce the exception with smaller code? Could you boil it down to just 10-15 lines that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: What is the JVM? Is it Sun or a custom one like JRocket?

Comment: java -version gives the following:
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: Sorry but this code causes gag reflex.

Comment: @c_maker - do you mean me coding style is so bad or what? BTW, have you ever seen a NPE similar to this one? I mean the : 23:51:39 at scal.SR$Con.access$5(Scal.java:1741). The .access$5 is particularly mysterious to me.

Comment: What is access? an inner class of Con? could you post more code around line 1741?

Comment: Show the `Con` class. And the code of `Utils.pValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Field "private final double upperConBound" is initialized from constructor of Con via static method

Java initializer order within the class source code is very important.
Try to place both upperConBound field declaration and static initializer before anything else within the Con class source code.